# Item in NavigationView remains disabled (onNavigationItemSelected)

Tags: android, navigationview, onitemselectedlistener

I have a list of items as follows: (act_pedido_drawer.xml)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:title="@string/nav_inicio"/>
    </group>
    <item 
        android:title="@string/nav_empresa"
        android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa_title">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa"
                android:title="@string/nav_mi_empresa"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_inventario"
                android:title="@string/nav_inventario"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_descuentos"
                android:title="@string/nav_descuentos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_clientes_proveedores"
                android:title="@string/nav_clientes_proveedores"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ventas"
                android:title="@string/nav_ventas"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_reportes"
                android:title="@string/nav_reportes"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_suscribirse"
                android:title="@string/nav_suscribirse"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/nav_cuenta">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gastos"
                android:title="@string/nav_gastos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_impuestos"
                android:title="@string/nav_impuestos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hardware"
                android:title="@string/nav_hardware"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_terminos_condiciones"
                android:title="@string/nav_terminos_condiciones"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cerrar_sesion"
                android:title="@string/nav_cerrar_sesion"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Which has a similar appearance to the following image:

[image]

The list is invoked from the following xml file, (app:menu="@menu/act_pedido_drawer"):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/act_bar_pedido"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_cabecera_act_pedido"
        app:menu="@menu/act_pedido_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The way to determine which item has been selected is as follows:

```js
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_mi_empresa_title:{

               break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_terminos_condiciones: {
               
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_mi_empresa: {
               
                break;
            }
           
            case R.id.nav_inventario: {
               
              
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_descuentos: {
               
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_clientes_proveedores: {
                
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_ventas:{
                
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_cerrar_sesion: {
               
                break;
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)          findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

For all the items it works correctly, except for the item nav_mi_empresa_title which can be seen in the image that seems to be disabled.

My question is: Is there a way to enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I simply put these two items inside menu:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:title="@string/nav_inicio"/>
    </group>
    <item 
        android:title="@string/nav_empresa">
        <menu>
            <item 
                android:title="@string/nav_empresa"
                android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa_title"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa"
                android:title="@string/nav_mi_empresa"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_inventario"
                android:title="@string/nav_inventario"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_descuentos"
                android:title="@string/nav_descuentos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_clientes_proveedores"
                android:title="@string/nav_clientes_proveedores"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ventas"
                android:title="@string/nav_ventas"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_reportes"
                android:title="@string/nav_reportes"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_suscribirse"
                android:title="@string/nav_suscribirse"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/nav_cuenta">
        <menu>
            <item 
                android:id="@+id/nav_cuenta"    
                android:title="@string/nav_cuenta">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gastos"
                android:title="@string/nav_gastos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_impuestos"
                android:title="@string/nav_impuestos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hardware"
                android:title="@string/nav_hardware"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_terminos_condiciones"
                android:title="@string/nav_terminos_condiciones"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cerrar_sesion"
                android:title="@string/nav_cerrar_sesion"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: That idea I had before, but it's a cumbersome solution, I think ... thanks for answering

Comment: @FabiánRomo Why don't you want to use this one?

Comment: Hi. Because two simial items appear ('Empresa' disabled and 'Empresa' enabled), what I want is only one and that of the feeling that contains others as in the figure attached to this thread.

Comment: The other idea that I have is to do this:

<item 
        android:title="">
        <menu>
            <item 
                android:title="@string/nav_empresa"
                android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa_title"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa"
                android:title="@string/nav_mi_empresa"/>


But a large empty space appears on the other items

Comment: So include all menu items into one menu without title

Comment: I continue with that idea but I add something else, in the answer of this thread is what was added.

Answer (score 0):

I will continue with the only idea suggested in this thread, but adding some lines of separation in some items.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:title="@string/nav_inicio"/>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:color="@color/colorDeshabilitado"
            android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa_titulo"
            android:title="@string/nav_empresa"/>
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/grp3" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_mi_empresa"
            android:title="@string/nav_mi_empresa"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inventario"
            android:title="@string/nav_inventario"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_descuentos"
            android:title="@string/nav_descuentos"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_clientes_proveedores"
            android:title="@string/nav_clientes_proveedores"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ventas"
            android:title="@string/nav_ventas"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_reportes"
            android:title="@string/nav_reportes"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_suscribirse"
            android:title="@string/nav_suscribirse"/>
    </group>

    <item
        android:title="@string/nav_cuenta"
        android:id="@+id/nav_titulo_cuenta">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gastos"
                android:title="@string/nav_gastos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_impuestos"
                android:title="@string/nav_impuestos"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hardware"
                android:title="@string/nav_hardware"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_terminos_condiciones"
                android:title="@string/nav_terminos_condiciones"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_cerrar_sesion"
                android:title="@string/nav_cerrar_sesion"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

[image]

Thanks to @D.B. for answering.